# Why am I getting bad data from my YQL query?

Tags: yahoo, yql

Within about a minute I made four identical queries. I get bad/inconsistent results. Some have missing data others have obvious bad data. Below please notice the four volume elements. They were each taken from consecutive queries. The first and last only return partial data. For volume 0 was returned. The second and third volume elements seem to imply that the volume went down. It should always increase during the same trading day. The markets are closed now anyway so they should all four return the same data, right? I have included the quote then the data returned from each of the four YHOO quotes.

```
<Volume>0</Volume>
<Volume>7882609</Volume>
<Volume>7310055</Volume>
<Volume>0</Volume>

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

<MyYhooQueries>
    <quote symbol="YHOO">
        <AverageDailyVolume>11189200</AverageDailyVolume>
        <Change/>
        <DaysLow/>
        <DaysHigh/>
        <YearLow>26.15</YearLow>
        <YearHigh>44.92</YearHigh>
        <MarketCapitalization>42.22B</MarketCapitalization>
        <LastTradePriceOnly>44.36</LastTradePriceOnly>
        <DaysRange/>
        <Name>Yahoo! Inc.</Name>
        <Symbol>YHOO</Symbol>
        <Volume>0</Volume>
        <StockExchange>NMS</StockExchange>
    </quote>
    <quote symbol="YHOO">
        <AverageDailyVolume>11241200</AverageDailyVolume>
        <Change>+0.01</Change>
        <DaysLow>44.03</DaysLow>
        <DaysHigh>44.72</DaysHigh>
        <YearLow>26.15</YearLow>
        <YearHigh>44.92</YearHigh>
        <MarketCapitalization>42.22B</MarketCapitalization>
        <LastTradePriceOnly>44.36</LastTradePriceOnly>
        <DaysRange>44.03 - 44.72</DaysRange>
        <Name>Yahoo! Inc.</Name>
        <Symbol>YHOO</Symbol>
        <Volume>7882609</Volume>
        <StockExchange>NMS</StockExchange>
    </quote>
    <quote symbol="YHOO">
        <AverageDailyVolume>11189200</AverageDailyVolume>
        <Change>-1.40</Change>
        <DaysLow>42.82</DaysLow>
        <DaysHigh>44.15</DaysHigh>
        <YearLow>26.15</YearLow>
        <YearHigh>44.92</YearHigh>
        <MarketCapitalization>40.89B</MarketCapitalization>
        <LastTradePriceOnly>42.96</LastTradePriceOnly>
        <DaysRange>42.82 - 44.15</DaysRange>
        <Name>Yahoo! Inc.</Name>
        <Symbol>YHOO</Symbol>
        <Volume>7310055</Volume>
        <StockExchange>NMS</StockExchange>
    </quote>
    <quote symbol="YHOO">
        <AverageDailyVolume>11189200</AverageDailyVolume>
        <Change/>
        <DaysLow/>
        <DaysHigh/>
        <YearLow>26.15</YearLow>
        <YearHigh>44.92</YearHigh>
        <MarketCapitalization>42.22B</MarketCapitalization>
        <LastTradePriceOnly>44.36</LastTradePriceOnly>
        <DaysRange/>
        <Name>Yahoo! Inc.</Name>
        <Symbol>YHOO</Symbol>
        <Volume>0</Volume>
        <StockExchange>NMS</StockExchange>
    </quote>
</MyYhooQueries>
```

Comment: So, what is the correct value?

Comment: It should be the current price of the stock. The recurring glitch is different today. It is easier to compare the current volume. It should never go down right? Today the recurring response has "905044" for volume. I just checked and the query returned "905044" and then "1270239" then running it again it returned "905044" again.

Comment: `It should never go down right?`, well, in my tests I did receive negative values. if the response of the YQL fluctuates, the problem is from source =  you can't do much about it _IMO_. Meanwhile, please check the [tour of Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for learn about how you can edit and improve your question. After thoe changes in your question, other users would be more interested in give you some answers.